# External web app location does not create directory under webapps in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

So far we have been using Tomcat 6 where we specify the war to be deployed in context.xml file under $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost as application1-context.xml, application2-context.xml. etc.

example application1-context.xml

```
<Context path="/myapps/app1" docBase="C:\warfiles\appOne.war"
        debug="0" privileged="true">
            <Loader className="MyCustomApplicationLoader"/>
            <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.SystemOutLogger" verbosity="4" timestamp="true"/>         
</Context>
```

This would create a folder myapps#app1 under $CATALINA_HOME/webapps folder.

But since migrating to Tomcat7, this does not happen any more.
Unless I have the war file "appone.war" directly under the tomcat appBase directory i.e. $CATALINA_HOME/webapps my war will not be unpacked into a folder under $CATALINA_HOME/webapps directory.

I have read this apache bug report:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51294&quot%3B&gt%3B51294&lt%3B/a&gt%3B

**Question**:
Is there any way we can force this behavior in tomcat 7?

Comment: Is `C:\warfiles\appOne.war` a File or a Directory?

Comment: @PeterRader C:\warfiles\appOne.war is a normal JEE war file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this issue has been [fixed in Tomcat version 7.0.48](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51294#c26) which, at the time of writing, is still in development. It's also been added to [version 8](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51294#c23).

**Edit:** I have managed to resolve this without having to wait for/use 7.0.48. In your context.xml file add `unpackWAR="false"` and specify the `virtualClasspath` attribute so it points to your target\classes folder like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context docBase="(path to .war file)">
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
            virtualClasspath="(path to folder contain .class files, 
                              usually {project folder}\target\classes\)"
            searchExternalFirst="true"
            unpackWAR="false" />
</Context>
```

- `searchExternalFirst` means that the class loader will look in your `virtualClasspath` folder before looking in the WEB-INF directory.
- `unpackWAR` is set to false because your war file will already be exploded in the /target/classes folder so there's no need for Tomcat to do it as well.

Hopefully this helps you too.

Comment: Yes I had figured this one out but it's a good response for people looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<Context unpackWARs="true" ...`

Files under conf/catalina/... should not be changed manual. They are created automatically if not exists on first start of the webapp. You should never change these files, delete them instead and let them be created new from tomcat itself (they are composed by the war's `/META-INF/context.xml`-File if exists).

Comment: I think the unpackWARS context attribute only works for war files under the webapps folder. If the war file is outside the CATALINA_HOME\webapps folder the attribute has no effect. And I am not sure about not creating the context file manually. Many applications using tomcat 6 does that.

Comment: The directory is not hardcoded, there should be no difference. You can create the context.xml but the copiing to conf/catalina should only be done by tomcat itself.